# Get alphabets only before number - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

How could I extract only alphabets of this column not considering characters after number? Also, there are situations where there are no numbers. In this case, is it possible to create a condition using CASE and WHEN to apply extraction condition only in cases where there are numbers?

Input:

```
medication_title
      
GLYXAMBI 25 MG E 5 MG
GLIFAGE XR 750 MG
AD TIL
SIMETICON GOTAS
```

Output:

```
medication_title       |  medication_commercialname
      
GLYXAMBI 25 MG E 5 MG     GLYXAMBI
GLIFAGE XR 750 MG         GLIFAGE XR
AD TIL                    AD TIL
SIMETICON GOTAS           SIMETICON GOTAS
```

Thanks!

Comment: In row 2, why wouldn't it be `GLIFAGE XR`

Comment: Use: `select substring('GLIFAGE XR 750 MG' from '[A-Z ]*');`

Comment: or can use `substring(medication_title from '[^\d/]*')` which doesn't mind case sensitivity.

Comment: @Isolated: Those medical people also still use fax machines, so probably also only capital letters.... 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `REGEXP_REPLACE()` looking for `\s*\d.*` (taking any string from 0+ whitespace chars a digit and 0+ more chars):

```
WITH input(medication_title) AS (
    VALUES ('GLYXAMBI 25 MG E 5 MG')
         , ('GLIFAGE XR 750 MG')
         , ('AD TIL')
         , ('SIMETICON GOTAS')
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(medication_title, '\s*\d.*','', 'g') FROM input;
```

Would return:

```
GLYXAMBI
GLIFAGE XR
AD TIL
SIMETICON GOTAS
```

See an online [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/98200/0)

Answer (score 1):

"The substring function with two parameters, substring(string from pattern), provides extraction of a substring that matches a POSIX regular expression pattern." (see: [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#:%7E:text=The%20substring%20function%20with%20two%20parameters%2C%20substring(string%20from%20pattern)%2C%20provides%20extraction%20of%20a%20substring%20that%20matches%20a%20POSIX%20regular%20expression%20pattern.))

The query:

```sql
SELECT rtrim(substring(medication_title from '[A-Z ]*')) FROM tablename:
```

should return the characters before any number.

The regular expression '[A-Z ]*' will match all (capital) letters from 'A' to 'Z' and a space, any number of times (because of the `*`).

The function `rtrim()` will remove the spaces at the end.

Comment: Nice, but beware of trailing spaces. Maybe nest in `TRIM()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT trim(substring(medication_title from '[^\d]*')) FROM tablename;
```

Output :

```
GLYXAMBI
GLIFAGE XR
AD TIL
SIMETICON GOTAS
```